# A imagem está ficando abaixo do menu

Tags: html, css

A imagem não está ficando...bem posicionada.  O que faço ?
Está com esse espaço em branco. É para ela...fica atrás do menu. Sem ficar com essa linha branca dividindo os dois.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, coloque também o código do seu arquivo CSS para que possamos ajudar. Provavelmente, o problema é relacionado ao atributo `z-index` do seu menu.

Comment: Sem o código fica dificil... tente dar um margin-top:0; padding-top:0; e adicionar um position a ela, e quando adicionado fazer um top: 0

Comment: Coloque o seu código HTML/CSS!!

Answer (score 0):

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 999;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>Menu</nav>
<header>imagem</header>
```

Caso não queira deixar o menu fixo no top, tire o position.